# Old Steam Furnace

Tags: electrical, heating, furnace, thermostat-c-wire, steam

I have a old steam furnace that is running fine now but it’s not hooked up to the switch or the transformer.

I have a brown wire (cable with brown insulation) containing a red and a white wire coming from the switch in the ceiling and a brown wire (cable with brown insulation) containing a red and a white wire coming from the thermostat.

I have 4 places to put wires in the LLWCO and an auto-water feeder.

Any help with this wiring?

Thanks

Comment: can you include a picture

Comment: How can a wire contain several wires? Do you mean cables? What switch? What transformer? Please revise to clarify the entire situation.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. That said, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Comment: What make and model are the various pieces involved here?  What do you have for a pressuretrol or vaporstat? Also, things that generate steam are labeled "boilers", generally speaking